# Percentage breakdown of categories of doubles in NBA

Tags: basketball, statistics, nba

A double consists of a player accumulating double digit number in one of the following categories per game: points, assists, rebounds, steals, and blocked shots. Achieving 2, 3, 4, or 5 doubles in a game is called double double, triple double, quadruple double, and quintuple double, respectively.

What is the percentage breakdown of each category for each of the 5 double types in the NBA? In other words, the percentage of a category for a given double type is the ratio of number of double that include that category to the number of all doubles.

Here is a hypothetical example only for double double type of what I'm looking for:

- 74% points
- 63% assists
- 45% rebounds
- 17% blocks
- 9% steals.

Percentage of each of the above categories is how often that category was part of double doubles. Of course a complete answer would have the same kind of percentage breakdown for all double types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the 1983-1984 NBA Season (presumably the earliest data Basketball Reference has for double- and triple-doubles) to the creation of this post, there have been:

- [number of type of double, double-doubles and beyond] (percentage among doubles, double-doubles and beyond)
- 71088 [double-doubles](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player_id=&match=game&year_min=1984&year_max=2017&age_min=0&age_max=99&team_id=&opp_id=&is_playoffs=N&round_id=&game_num_type=&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_day=&game_location=&game_result=&is_starter=&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&is_dbl_dbl=Y&is_trp_dbl=&order_by=date_game&order_by_asc=&offset=71000) (98.07%)

  - 70970 [points](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player_id=&match=game&year_min=1984&year_max=2017&age_min=0&age_max=99&team_id=&opp_id=&is_playoffs=N&round_id=&game_num_type=&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_day=&game_location=&game_result=&is_starter=&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&is_dbl_dbl=Y&is_trp_dbl=&order_by=pts&order_by_asc=&offset=70900) (99.8% of all double-doubles)
  - 15861 [assists](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player_id=&match=game&year_min=1984&year_max=2017&age_min=0&age_max=99&team_id=&opp_id=&is_playoffs=N&round_id=&game_num_type=&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_day=&game_location=&game_result=&is_starter=&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&is_dbl_dbl=Y&is_trp_dbl=&order_by=ast&order_by_asc=&offset=15800) (22.3%)
  - 56631 [rebounds](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player_id=&match=game&year_min=1984&year_max=2017&age_min=0&age_max=99&team_id=&opp_id=&is_playoffs=N&round_id=&game_num_type=&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_day=&game_location=&game_result=&is_starter=&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&is_dbl_dbl=Y&is_trp_dbl=&order_by=trb&order_by_asc=&offset=56600) (79.7%)
  - 16 [steals](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=game&year_min=1984&year_max=2017&is_playoffs=N&age_min=0&age_max=99&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&is_dbl_dbl=Y&order_by=stl) (0.02%)
  - 99 [blocks](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=game&year_min=1984&year_max=2017&is_playoffs=N&age_min=0&age_max=99&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&is_dbl_dbl=Y&order_by=blk) (0.14%)
- 1398 [triple-doubles](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player_id=&match=game&year_min=1984&year_max=2017&age_min=0&age_max=99&team_id=&opp_id=&is_playoffs=N&round_id=&game_num_type=&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_day=&game_location=&game_result=&is_starter=&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&is_dbl_dbl=&is_trp_dbl=Y&order_by=date_game&order_by_asc=&offset=1300) (1.93%)

  - 1397 [points](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player_id=&match=game&year_min=1984&year_max=2017&age_min=0&age_max=99&team_id=&opp_id=&is_playoffs=N&round_id=&game_num_type=&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_day=&game_location=&game_result=&is_starter=&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&is_dbl_dbl=&is_trp_dbl=Y&order_by=pts&order_by_asc=&offset=1300) (99.9% of all triple-doubles)
  - 1334 [assists](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15496/percentage-breakdown-of-categories-of-doubles-in-nba) (95.4%)
  - 1394 [rebounds](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player_id=&match=game&year_min=1984&year_max=2017&age_min=0&age_max=99&team_id=&opp_id=&is_playoffs=N&round_id=&game_num_type=&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_day=&game_location=&game_result=&is_starter=&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&is_dbl_dbl=&is_trp_dbl=Y&order_by=trb&order_by_asc=&offset=1300) (99.7%)
  - 8 [steals](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player_id=&match=game&year_min=1984&year_max=2017&age_min=0&age_max=99&team_id=&opp_id=&is_playoffs=N&round_id=&game_num_type=&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_day=&game_location=&game_result=&is_starter=&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&is_dbl_dbl=&is_trp_dbl=Y&order_by=trb&order_by_asc=&offset=1300) (0.057%)
  - 64 [blocks](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=game&year_min=1984&year_max=2017&is_playoffs=N&age_min=0&age_max=99&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&is_trp_dbl=Y&order_by=blk) (4.58%).
- 4 [quadruple-doubles](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leaders/quadruple-double-most-times.html) (0.06%) <sub>[(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_(basketball)#Quadruple-double)</sub>

  - 4 points (100% of all quadruple-doubles)
  - 4 assists (100%)
  - 4 rebounds (100%)
  - 1 steal (25%)
  - 3 blocks (75%)
- 0 [quintuple-doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_(basketball)#Quintuple-double) (0%)

I see a requirement for "single-doubles" and "single" category breakdown...I'll update this post if I collect that information.

Comment: I added the comment example to the question. I tried my best to convey that I wanted the breakdown by introducing the categories - otherwise they are not related to the question. But it clearly wasn't enough

Comment: With all the double talk (no pun intended), I became lost. It's almost a tongue twister haha.

Comment: If you think you can edit it to make the point more clear feel free to do so

Comment: It's much clearer now with your example and "Percentage of a category is how often that category was part of a double double." I don't think I can make it clearer than that. In any case, I added double-double category breakdowns.